# Why did Johan want to commit suicide?

Tags: monster

Well, I just finished monster today and I really enjoyed it. I thought I grasped the meaning to Johan suicide but after searching on the internet people were writing different interpretations so I would like you to hear my interpretation and correct me if I am wrong.

The second to last episode (episode 73) Johan and Nina recollected a memory in which Franz said that the twins were not monsters and are special. By recollecting this memory Johan attempted a suicide which will be led by Tenma's hand.

My interpretation into why Johan wanted to commit suicide is because of the recollected memory of Franz saying that they are special hence Johan at the moment of recollecting that memory he cried because that's when he realized what he was doing was wrong hence the suicide attempt and the reason why Nina forgave him. Am I correct?

Comment: As per [this meta post](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4014/how-do-we-respond-to-is-my-theory-right-questions), it's recommended to put your interpretation as the answer so that it can be voted accordingly, and for others to be able to answer your core question.

Answer (score -1):

What I think happened in *Monster* is, Johan was the nameless monster. Somehow he might have concluded that the story always ends with the nameless monster being the last person alive, so Johan planned the perfect suicide destroying every trace of him. Now that Tenma learned his real name, I guess he thought he was not the nameless monster anymore, so he committed suicide.

As for being psychopath, maybe it happened when he started to question himself if he was the wanted child as the mother gave Nina to Bonaparte. At that particular moment, he was reading that nameless monster story. Then I guess at 511 Kinderheim when he forgot everything, he became a loose nut and his memory of wanting to be the nameless monster (last person alive) came back when he read the book at the library, and then he planned the perfect suicide.

So I guess that's when the real story starts, and I also think that Nina always had a clue of Johan wanting to be the nameless monster.